# Join Attributes by Location incorrect summary attributes in joined table

Tags: qgis-processing

I am using QGIS 2.18.3 to join points to polygons with a Precision setting of 20.0 to select any polygon within radius of my point. I am taking attribute of intersecting features with the point layer as the target. The resulting joined layer attribute table confuses the field names. By checking results with a small test data set it is clear that the field names in the joined layer are displaced. I have 5 numeric fields in the polygon layer, two of which are Integer, the rest Real. The joined layer takes the summary values from the 3rd numeric field, but labels it as the 1st numeric field etc. I checked all values and apart from displacement all are correct. I am a novice user but is this a bug?